# Filter specifik patern in a complex file

Tags: grep, uniq

I have this logfile and im trying to avoid printing the text containing patern" APLHA".

```
   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** ALPHA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
* KJENRFKES DFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
CL mesukww juwaehdiearfa
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
*C KJENRFKESDFJ ksludhieokdaewmdp
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** BETA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

I tried via this way but not successful.It prints the rest of the text, except "ALPHA"

cat logfile |grep -v "ALPHA"
result:

```
+++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

What i expect is the whole log containing "ALPHA" is not printed, like hereunder:

```
 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
* KJENRFKES DFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
CL mesukww juwaehdiearfa
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
*C KJENRFKESDFJ ksludhieokdaewmdp
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** BETA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

Can you please advise on any other solution to this case?

Regards Dom

Comment: When I run your command `cat logfile |grep -v "ALPHA"` which actually could be written `grep -v "ALPHA" Input_file` too, working fine for me. Could you please check once if you have control M characters in your Input_file? By doing `cat -v Input_file` and let us know then?

Comment: i tried your suggestion,"grep -v "ALPHA" Input_file " and the output si the same as before. Regarding the cat -v command, I did not find any control M character present.

Comment: @Dominik , if the solution provided here help you then you should also appreciate the answer by up-voting them.  you can accept only one answer but can appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}!/ALPHA/' file
```

Comment: @Dominik at SO you accept answers that solved your problem. otherwise, nobody is gonna help you anymore. Check your question history, and accept answers.

Comment: I didn't realize how to accept the answer, this is the reason why I haven't clicked the "accept answer". Now I find it , thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution using `perl`'s slurp mode(`-00` to enable). This will tell `perl` to consider paragraphs are one record not the lines. Later is clear, print only if `ALPHA` is not present.

```
perl -00 -ne  'print if  !/ALPHA/' inputfile
   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
* KJENRFKES DFJKLSDFJEDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
CL mesukww juwaehdiearfa
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

   +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
*C KJENRFKESDFJ ksludhieokdaewmdp
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-

 +++ skdfhahjsahsdjk >
** BETA EDFJDJFKLJDKFJKSDLFJL
   SDFSDGDRGRTG
   WEFETTFYRT #168113++-
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Yes , it seems works fine also with your suggestion, I appreciate it :)